# Vaadin and Spring boot problems

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have lately started to experiment with Vaadin as a means of providing the UI for an application that I am building.

At the time being, I am just playing around with simple examples in order to get a  grasp on how the framework works.

Now, I tried today to incorporate some UI elements to my already in place spring boot application.

I am facing some problems when trying to get the various views to show. Seems that the view mappings are not working, as I am getting the classic spring error regarding the mapping not found.

At first I thought that I was having issues with my `RestController` mappings (the app also exposes some Rest endpoints). In order to overcome this, I created a custom `WebConfiguration` that maps all the `RestController` annotated classes to another base api path (e.g. 'ws'). After doing so, I am still unable to access my Vaadin created UI though. I have tried annotating the UI class with `@SpringUI(name = '/test')` but it seems that this does not work too.

I have tried searching online for a solution to this but I was unable to find anything useful.

I am new to Vaadin and thus I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Seems that after some digging around the project I have traced down the problem. For some reason, when I added the maven depedencies, I used the vaadin-starter without a version. Same goes for the vaadin-bom dep but this time without version. Even though the project was running fine, idea's maven inspection was picking errors. Upon correcting those, I was able to get everything up and running.

Weird problem though

Comment: Can you update **UI class with SpringUI(name = '/test')**  with calling part.

Comment: Did that in the begginning and it was not working. As I mentioned before, I did manage to resolve the problem, but it still strikes me as weird as to why the dependencies were not working properly.

Comment: May be deprecated, try with latest version maven dependency.

Comment: Also, if you solved your problem, you should post an answer explaining how did you do it.